# Is the Google Play Game Services playerId static

Tags: android, plugins, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I'm currently developing a game with unity using the [unity google plugin](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity).

I want to use the Google login as one of 3 login keys to access my game servers and want to know if the playeriD  [(Google Play Game Services > games.players.get)](https://console.developers.google.com/project/1031907279911/apiui/api/games/method/games.players.get) would be static. regardless from where they login from.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you look at the Google+ profile link - like https://plus.google.com/116518204578946283219/posts, the playerId is the unique number identifying Google+ users.